# NPM is corrupted?

Tags: node.js, npm

so I tried installing a package with NPM but since it was giving me an error, I tried to force the installation, which resulted in my NPM being completely corrupted.

For instance, when I try to run my react app with `npm run start`, I get in the error logs :

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\basse\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'cache',
0 verbose cli   'clear'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.4
2 info using node@v16.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 8ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 8ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\basse\Desktop\Website\full-mint-website\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 8ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\basse\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 25ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 26ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
23 verbose logfile C:\Users\basse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-17T17_50_07_578Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 41ms
28 timing command:cache Completed in 0ms
29 verbose stack Error: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
29 verbose stack   by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
29 verbose stack   data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
29 verbose stack   want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
29 verbose stack   instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
29 verbose stack   not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
29 verbose stack
29 verbose stack   On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
29 verbose stack   or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
29 verbose stack   cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
29 verbose stack   temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
29 verbose stack
29 verbose stack   If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
29 verbose stack   with --force.
29 verbose stack     at Cache.clean (C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\cache.js:124:15)
29 verbose stack     at Cache.exec (C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\cache.js:107:27)
29 verbose stack     at Npm.exec (C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:150:22)
29 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\basse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:66:5)
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\basse\Desktop\Website\full-mint-website
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\basse\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clear"
33 verbose node v16.14.0
34 verbose npm  v8.5.4
35 error As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
35 error   by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
35 error   data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
35 error   want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
35 error   instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
35 error   not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
35 error
35 error   On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
35 error   or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
35 error   cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
35 error   temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
35 error
35 error   If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
35 error   with --force.
36 verbose exit 1
37 timing npm Completed in 2759ms
38 verbose code 1
39 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
39 error     C:\Users\basse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-17T17_50_07_578Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried cleaning the cache with `npm cache clean` but I get the same error...

Comment: Remove the package, try to uninstall npm and reinstall latest version. Then try to reinstall package.

Comment: Did you try the other things recommended in the message? such as `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache`

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with possible `npm` / `node_modules` corruption, the first step is always to wipe out `node_modules` entirely and re-populate it:

1. Remove `node_modules` entirely:

   On *nix: `rm -rf node_modules`

   On Windows: `rd /s /q node_modules`
2. Repopulate it: `npm install`.

If that doesn't work, you may have to uninstall `npm` entirely and reinstall it (usually as part of [re]installing Node.js).